State is reverting back even after i confirmed its change
so when i click evalute this expression '3+5*6-2/4' then result state is set to 32.5
after that clear function is being triggered and it sets the state to '' and after that when i press 5 it reverts the previous state which is '32.5' and add '5' into it making it '32.55' this behaviour is not observed first few test
i am using fcc test bundle to test the code but before i can complete it ran into this problem
and below given are logs of the print statements
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './JavaScriptCalculator.css';
function JavaScriptCalculator() {
    const [exp, setExp] = useState('');
    const [ans, setAns] = useState('0');
    const [s, ss] = useState(true);
    function setstate(e, a, s = true,v='') {
        console.log(e, a, s,v);
        setExp(e);
        setAns(a);
        ss(s);
    }
    function click(v) {
        switch (v) {
            case 'A': setstate('', '0',true,v);setstate('', '0',true,v); break;
            case 'E': setstate(eval(exp), eval(exp), false,v); break;
            default:  setstate(exp + v, '',true,v); break;
        }
    }
    return (
        <div id="calculatorbackground">
            <div id="calculator">
                <div id="display">
                    <div id="Expression">{s && exp}</div><div id="Answere">{ans}</div>
                </div>
                <div onClick={() => click('A')} id="clear">AC</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('C')} id="back">{'<-'}</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('/')} data-value="/" id="divide">/</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('*')} data-value="*" id="multiply">x</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('7')} data-value="7" id="seven">7</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('8')} data-value="8" id="eight">8</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('9')} data-value="9" id="nine">9</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('-')} data-value="-" id="subtract">-</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('4')} data-value="4" id="four">4</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('5')} data-value="5" id="five">5</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('6')} data-value="6" id="six">6</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('+')} data-value="+" id="add">+</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('1')} data-value="1" id="one">1</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('2')} data-value="2" id="two">2</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('3')} data-value="3" id="three">3</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('E')} id="equals">=</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('0')} data-value="0" id="zero">0</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('.')} data-value="." id="decimal">.</div>
                <div onClick={() => click('L')}>L</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default JavaScriptCalculator;

 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
5  true 5
5*  true *
5*1  true 1
5*1+  true +
5*1+5  true 5
5*1+5+  true +
5*1+5+9  true 9
5*1+5+92  true 2
102 102 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
 0 true A
1  true 1
12  true 2
123  true 3
 0 true A
 0 true A
3  true 3
3+  true +
3+5  true 5
3+5*  true *
3+5*6  true 6
3+5*6-  true -
3+5*6-2  true 2
3+5*6-2/  true /
3+5*6-2/4  true 4
32.5 32.5 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
32.55  true 5
32.55-  true -
32.55-9  true 9
32.55-9+  true +
32.55-9+5  true 5
28.549999999999997 28.549999999999997 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
0  true 0
00  true 0
000  true 0
 0 true A
 0 true A
5  true 5
5.  true .
5..  true .
5..0  true 0
 0 true A
 0 true A
1  true 1
10  true 0
10.  true .
10.5  true 5
10.5-  true -
10.5-5  true 5
10.5-5.  true .
10.5-5.5  true 5
5 5 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
55  true 5
55*  true *
55*5  true 5
55*5.  true .
55*5.5  true 5
302.5 302.5 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
5  true 5
5*  true *
5*-  true -
5*-5  true 5
-25 -25 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
-255  true 5
-255*  true *
-255*-  true -
-255*-+  true +
-255*-+5  true 5
1275 1275 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
5  true 5
5-  true -
5-2  true 2
3 3 false 'E'
3/  true /
3/2  true 2
1.5 1.5 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
1.55  true 5
1.55+  true +
1.55+5  true 5
6.55 6.55 false 'E'
6.55+  true +
6.55+3  true 3
9.55 9.55 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A
2  true 2
2/  true /
2/7  true 7
0.2857142857142857 0.2857142857142857 false 'E'
 0 true A
 0 true A```


I don't think it's clear what your issue is. Can you simplify your code and describe it in something other than a single run-on sentence?

the issue is when i click the clear button the state is shown  to be null
but when i click any other number the stack goes back and pick the value which it had previously
